# apache crashes after moving to a new server

Tags: php, apache-2.2, authorization

I've just moved a bunch of my sites to a new server
Everything seems to work fine except of one site.
I have changed a domain for that one.
The old copy of site on the previous domain works fine.

When I try to login to that site it just does not load. 
Apache log files are empty.

I suggest it's not apache or php misconfiguration (because the other sites on the new server work fine), and there are no files occasinally corrupted during the transfer (i've tried to overwrite the files of this site several times).

where the problem could be?

Comment: This 100% belongs to serverfault

Comment: but all the other sites work fine, authorization works fine there too. so it can't be session creating error or something, right?

Comment: A few details: when I login, the site goes into the infinite "Awaiting response from domain.com..."
after that site is not responding anymore, but if I open it with another browser, it does open, until I try to authorize.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without any details. What does mean "crashes" ? You should look in your error_log and also check that your VirtualServer in Apache configuration is correct.

You should also try to restrict access to that site for a second and try to die(); in specific script. When it works, (it dies() without crashing the server), you can move die() to the other parts of the script. Just try to debug it and try to find the part that is crashing your server

Comment: when i try to authorize the site does not respond anymore.

Comment: @user1010936: it means that apache process crashes or it is **just not responding to your request?**